# Magento 2 I am trying to upload CSV file for the configurable products. getting error like attribute code does not exists

Tags: magento2.3, configurable-product, import

I am trying to upload this `CSV` file for the configurable products.

Unfortunately, the error I'm facing is

> 1. Column configurable_variations: Attribute with code "rom" does not exist or is missing from product attribute set

I've assigned to attribute code to attribute set.
However, when I checked my `additional_attributes` and `configurable_variations` attributes, it seems like I got all of the definition of the attribute there already.

Please have a look into the file and helps me with the answer. Much appreciate it.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16TmSdzGJD-BCQGTbI3i2GVkjAtAq6wKEXmk5JnncTy8/edit?usp=sharing